# elasticsearch update a set

Tags: elasticsearch, mvel

Im trying to update a list fields only if the item is not already in the list.

what's wrong with:

```
curl -X POST 'http://localhost:9200/my_index/my_doc/id/_update' -d 
'{ "script":
"{if !(ctx._source.my_field contains new_item) {ctx._source.my_field.add(new_item)}}" 
, "params":{"new_item":"hopefully_new_text"}}'
```

This adds the item anyway, even if it exists.

any smarter way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's one of the many strange things about MVEL parsing behavior. If you will remove the outermost `{` `}`, you will see that you have a syntax error in your if statement and if you will fix that error, everything will work:

```
curl -X POST 'http://localhost:9200/my_index/my_doc/id/_update' -d  '{
    "script": "if (!(ctx._source.my_field contains new_item)) {ctx._source.my_field.add(new_item)}",
    "params": {
        "new_item": "hopefully_new_text"
    }
}
'
```